# How do I get rid of this line and gap?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to this and I've really got no clue what I'm doing.
There's this line on my model
[image: line on chest]

I'm not sure what it is or how to get rid of it. There is also a line on the shoulder as well as a little gap that I would like to get rid of. I'm not sure how.
[image: gap]
Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: This looks like maybe an issue with doubles, but it would really help if you uploaded the .blend file.

Comment: Yeah I second that, it's probably doubled verts, push W in edit mode and choose Remove  Doubles, 99% percent sure that'll solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's *Mesh > Clean Up > Merge By Distance > Enter*

Pressing <kbd>W</kbd> did not do anything, though I think that may be a personal issue for me.